# Handling orientation on lockscreen for an android app

Tags: android, orientation, lockscreen, android-orientation

Testing my application on my Galaxy S2 I have a problem whenever the screen is turned off and back on.  My application is locked into landscape by the manifest.  The lock screen forces the application into some weird orientation where it is rendering portrait but displaying it was landscape (as in the right 2/5 of my screen is black and the portrait rendering goes off the bottom).  The application is also not responsive in this state.  If I quickly hit home (or back) and recall the application it works perfect.

As well, if I use a different lock screen (tried with PowerAmp) it works flawlessly.

So can anyone help me understand why this is screwing up and how to fix the orientation whenever this happens?

I can avoid this by avoiding the lock screen through a flag (window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)) but I don't have any other reason to avoid a lock screen and would like to know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This sound like a problem that is unique to the S2. Have you tried your app on the emulator or any other devices. It may just be that the S2 implements some part of android incorrectly.

Comment: No I haven't tested elsewhere, just thought it would be worth fixing.  I'll try on an emulator now and a friends phone tomorrow.

This happens to every other app on the s2 as well, it just looks like they recover from it almost instantly after the unlock.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the orientation problem in your application try to use this for your activity like this

```
<activity android:configchanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

in your Android Manfiest file.

Comment: I already have this actually.  The problem is the galaxy s2 lock screen somehow forces apps to render in portrait when they shouldn't be.